# Marionette -what does "startWithParent = false" causes?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

As describ [here](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.application.module.md#preventing-auto-start-of-modules) , the - `startWithParent = false` on the sub-Module causes to sub-Moudle to not start with the application.

As I got it , after `startWithParent = false` in the sub-Moudue , the `MyApp.start()` should not be execute the sub-Module `initializer` .

But when I try the follow  -

```
MyApp = new Marionette.Application();
MyApp.module("SubModule", function () {
    // prevent starting with parent
    this.startWithParent = false;
    // Logs
    console.log("Sub Module Created !"); 
});
MyApp.start();
```

The `Sub Module Created !` Logs , means that the sub-Module `initializer` took action .

Can you please clarify it for me ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code inside

```
MyApp.module("SubModule", function () {
  ...
});
```

is module definition and calls immediately. To add initializer to module you should write something like:

```
MyApp = new Marionette.Application();
MyApp.module("SubModule", function () {
    // prevent starting with parent
    this.startWithParent = false;

    this.addInitializer(function(){
        console.log("Sub Module Initialized !");
    });

    console.log("Sub Module Defined !");
});
MyApp.start();
console.log("My App Started !");
MyApp.SubModule.start();
```

And in your console you will see:

> ```
> Sub Module Defined !
> My App Started !
> Sub Module Initialized !
> ```